# asp.net ItemTemplate : ITemplate

Tags: asp.net, itemtemplate

```
public class TheItemTemplate : ITemplate
{

    //....

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Who calls this method? And when is it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, this method is called when the control tree is created, so in the `CreateChildControls()` method. This `CreateChildControls` method is part of the Control inheritance hierarchy and is typically overriden by subclassed controls.

So, the control to which the template belongs *should* call `InstantiateIn()` in `CreateChildControls`.